# Creating a subclass of UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I have a subclass of UIView like so:

```
@implementation AView

- (UIView *) buildBestView
{
    UIView *test = [[UIView alloc] init];

    return test;
}

@end
```

If I include AView.h in my controller, how do I call this method?

Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: i want to abstract a column of views

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare your method in your **Interface**

```
@interface AVView : UIView

- (UIView *) buildBestView;

@end
```

Use that in the other class

```
AVView *avView = [[AVView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake:(0,0, 100, 100)];

[avView buildBestView];
```

Comment: I want the subclass to do the creating tho

Comment: do you want to call this method from subclass itself?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you creating a class method instead like this:

```
+ (UIView *) buildBestView // Note the "+" instead of the "-"
{
    UIView *test = [[UIView alloc] init];

    return test;
}
```

Then you can call it like this

```
AView *aview = [AView buildBestView];
// Do whatever you need with aview
```

Comment: Then how do you get to call test?

Comment: my code can't see buildBestview in intellisense